# Битрикс. Форма добавления/редактирования на странице элемента инфоблока. Как заставить форму подхватывать данные редактируемого элемента?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно создать форму редактирования элемента инфоблока.

В стандартном наборе инструментов присутствует компонент `bitrix:iblock.element.add.form`, называемый так же `"Форма добавления / редактирования"`.

С добавлением компонент справляется прекрасно, но как его можно использовать для редактирования, я понять так и не смог. Желательно организовать редактирование через форму, используемую для добавления.

Компонент генерирует форму, которая в случае редактирования, видимо, должна заполняться значениями свойств и полей элемента. Компонент привязан к соответствующему инфоблоку (как упоминалось выше, добавление новых элементов происходит корректно), но он не подхватывает параметры GET (`"?ID=123"`), в какой бы форме я их ему не подсовывал  в надежде, что их то ему и не хватает для корректной работы. Форма просто рисуется с пустыми полями.

В справочных материалах эта тема освещена очень бедно. В основном делается акцент на функционал добавления, либо на модификацию формы редактирования элемента через режим правки в панели разработчика.

Собственно, вопрос: в чем может быть моя ошибка? И какова обычная практика реализации формы редактирования элемента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Вам надо указать `$_REQUEST["CODE"]`, именно оттуда компонент берет ID элемента для редактирования.

Как правило, это обычно закрывается за "Обработкой адресов": `/bitrix/admin/urlrewrite_list.php?lang=ru`, чтобы получилось нечто вроде `/friendlypage/edit/123/`

Comment: Да, это работает. Вы восстановили мою веру в гармоничное устройство мироздания! Благодаря вашему ответу в мире стало на 500 строк говнокода меньше. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье!
Странно, что так долго не нашлось ответа на ваш вопрос -- мне было достаточно один раз посмотреть в код компонента:)

Comment: а может быть расскажете подробно, как это осуществить? ато с ваших слов, блондинке, не все понятно

Comment: Ребята вы не могли бы объяснить как вызывать компонент bitrix:iblock.element.add.form в режиме редактирования? Вот мой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512015